# Debugging tool for managed code

Tags: debugging, windbg, visual-studio-debugging, managed-code

I am new to C# and wondering whether "**windbg**" or "**Visual Studio Debugger**" would be better tool for debugging managed code?

For the past couple of years, I have been doing development in C++ and I am comfortable in using **windbg** as compared to **Visual Studio debugger**. However, I am not sure whether **windbg** would work best in the case of managed code as well?

Is there any other debugging tool besides **windbg** and **Visual Studio Debugger** which works even better than these in debugging managed code?

Comment: I have not used windb in ages so can't compare, but the debugger in Visual Studio is quite full-featured.

Comment: What kind of application you going to debug? In general Visual Studio debugger performs perfect, you can attach to a process or launch application with attached debugger from the Visual Studio directly

Comment: My development is not focused to some specific feature/implementation. Code may cover wide range of implementation with complexity level: Medium to high (IPC Communication, COM, Memory corruption)

Comment: I used windbg to find memory leaks for my WPF application... can it get any "managed" than this? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinDbg needs SOS or PSSCOR2/4 to debug managed code, but with either of those you get a very powerful debugger. However, I would not recommend using only WinDbg for managed code as support for source debugging is rather limited at the moment (and has been for a long time). You might also want to get SOSEX as it complements SOS/PSSCOR with additional useful commands.

In my experience Visual Studio works very well for regular debugging and WinDbg+SOS/PSSCOR2 is excellent for all those hairy problems such as memory issues, deadlocks and so forth that VS doesn't handle very well.